# Can I run anaconda from a bat file?

Tags: python, batch-file

I just updated my python install to Anaconda 4.4.0

Problem is I can't run my python scripts from .bat files now.

I'm developing with tensorflow so I have a python 3.5 environment specifically for it. Previously I could access that environment in a .bat file with the line

```
call activate tensorflow
```

now that gives the error

```
'activate' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Ideally I'd like to keep using .bat files so that I can run my training routines with a double click instead of having to type out the same commands every time.

Does anyone know how to run a .bat in the Anaconda Prompt, or access a python environment from cmd without the 'activate' keyword?

Comment: I don't know [tag:python] or [tag:tensorflow], but here's some shot. First: That error showed up because there is no `activate` command. You may want to try `"activate tensorflow"` instead. Second: `call` is used to call a batch script. Though that doesn't really matter.

Comment: **WTF** that actually worked. The way I had it before `call` had to be used, and then looking it up earlier today I saw including `call` as a correction for multiple peoples questions. I'm not sure if I should feel sheepish for asking a stupid question or vindicated about how nonsensical it all is. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Activate` is not a standard Windows command, so it throws an error.

I guess you mean the two words as one command. If so, quote them like so:

```
call "activate tensorflow"
```

Here is a comparison of how command processor sees the two quoteing method:

> ```
> >call activate tensorflow
>   (run the program "activate" with the parameter "tensorflow")
>
> >call "activate tensorflow"
>   (run the program "activate tensorflow" with no parameters)
> ```

And finally, the `call` command is used to call a script/ subroutine, though leaving it intact won't do anything extra.